# Mapping Entity Framework Code First to dynamically named tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm currently using EF5 in a project with a legacy database. The legacy application uses dynamically build tables (xxxx_year, yyyy_year) to store "year based data". I've been trying to find a way to dynamically map the ef entities (xxxx, yyyy, etc) to the tables, based on the year property value, but I always end up getting the "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created." error. Can anyone give me some ideas on how to accomplish this ?

I found some old blog posts talking about edm mapping, where we can separate mapping tables based on some property value (kind of horizontal partitioning), but I can't find any pointers on how to accomplish the same using code first.

Thanks, P

Comment: What is the database platform?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping configuration for each domain object, you can tell EF that the corresponding table name for an entity is different from the entity name itself.

If your class is called YyyyYear, it can point to a table called "2012_year" by specifying the name in its mapping file.

e.g.

```
// 1 entity class per db table
public class YyyyYear
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

// 1 mapping file for entity
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public class YyyyYearMap: EntityTypeConfiguration
{
  public YyyyYearMap()
  {
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id); 
    this.ToTable("2012_year");
  }
}

// your db context class (derives from DbContext)
using System.Data.Entity;
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
  // 1 db set for every entity/table
  public DbSet YyyyYears { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    // 1 mapping file for every entity/table
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new YyyyYearMap());
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but I have a blog post with step-by-step instructions, a working sample, and how to resolve common issues.

http://wakeupandcode.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I've managed to solve it in another way (merging "previous years" tables into a big one called xxxhistory and partitioning it inside Sql Server. The only drawback is that I always end up with current year + history models. Your solution would work, but it seems to me that it would require to create a new mapping every year and that's not possible :-)